# What is the standard method in rust to decompose a unicode character? (remove accents and other marks)

Tags: rust, unicode, nfd

What is the correct method in rust, to take a character such as ἄ return the normal α without accents?  (For example, do a unicode `nfc` to `nfd` conversion so that the α is separated from the ᾽ and ´)

I suspect this [rust documentation](https://docs.rs/unicode-normalization/latest/unicode_normalization/char/fn.decompose_canonical.html) page reveals the function I need, but there is no example code  which gives me a clue how to use it.

https://docs.rs/unicode-normalization/latest/unicode_normalization/char/fn.decompose_canonical.html

I know this rather hacky convoluted code works, but it seems not the correct option:

```
let s:Vec<char> = c.to_string().nfkd().collect();
s[0] // <--- unaccented
```

Comment: The NFD of "ἄ" (U+1F04) isn't "α" (U+03B1), it's "ἄ" (U+03B1, U+0313, U+0301)

Comment: Unicode decomposition results in 7 bits ASCII characters and combining diacritical marks, the accents. One can replace all _combining diacritical marks_ using regex. There will remain special characters, like comma like quotes.

Comment: @Joop U+03B1 is neither a 7 bit ASCII char nor a combinig diacritical mark, your statement therefore can't be quite right.

Comment: Apologies if it's not clear, but in the question heading I specifically ask about removing the accents and other marks. NFD is useful here because the first character will be the actual character, and the subsequent characters are the accent marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you pass in is called for each character in the decomposition. The first character it's called for is the one you are interested in. Example code:

```
use unicode_normalization::char::decompose_canonical;

fn main () {
    let mut base_char = None;
    decompose_canonical('ἄ', |c| { base_char.get_or_insert(c); });
    dbg!(base_char);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b174333c7ab054fe0ab25d62658fb7ad)